# Is Invasion of the Body Snatchers a misnomer?

Tags: prepositions

In the phrase "invasion of Vietnam", Vietnam is being invaded. It seems whenever I see "invasion of (SOME COUNTRY NAME)" in any English text, the country in question is being invaded and is not the invader.

That is why I am confused by the movie title. Is that a misnomer or is it that "invasion of X" can have two meanings?

Comment: Try Googling  *invasion of the barbarians, invasion of the Huns* and *invasion of the Mongols*. Not to mention the rock-and-roll *[British invasion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Invasion)*.

Comment: Though I understand the meaning of "Invasion of the Body Snatchers", I think "Invasion ***by*** the Body Snatchers" would have been clearer (though maybe not as "catchy"!) :-)

Comment: Good question. I like the Invasion of the Pentagon answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preposition *of* can convey a form of possessive that reflects the actor. For example, one of the definitions in the [Compact OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/of?q=of) is

> expressing the relationship between an author, artist, or composer and their works collectively:
>
> *the plays of Shakespeare*
>
> *the paintings of Rembrandt*

These are *the plays **by** Shakespeare* [not the ones he bought for his bookshelves] and *the paintings **by** Rembrandt* [not the one hanging on his walls].

*The Invasion **of** the Body Snatchers* means *The invasion **by** the Bodysnatchers*

As to your question, can *invasion of* have two meanings? Yes.

If the object of the preposition refers to a geography or an effective place (e.g., *the invasion of government by lobbyists*), *invasion of* conveys the place/object of invasion, but if the object of the preposition is a person/organization/group/entity, *invasion of* conveys the actor/moving force (*the invasion of the cicadas in our quiet town*).

And there are times it may not be clear.

> What are you most concerned about?
>
> The invasion of the Pentagon!

(Are you afraid that the Pentagon is being raided by some dangerous force, or that the Pentagon is the dangerous force infiltrating itself into your realm?)

Comment: Is COED supposed to be OED or is this another dictionary? Or perhaps a Freudian slip?

Comment: @terdon COED was meant to convey Compact OED, the only version that is availble free online (absent a university/library connection). I have no idea if this is a standard abbreviation for this most helpful resource.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Searching google for COED returns a very different usage of the term.

Comment: @terdon Sometimes a COED is not a coed.

Comment: @terdon I have reverted to my usual abbreviation of *Compact OED* to avoid confusion. Now let's wait for the questions as to whether OED means *Old, Esoteric and Disdainful*

Answer (score 3):

"The invasion of X" can have two different meanings, depending on whether X refers to a place or a group/people/species/race, and there is absolutely no ambiguity.

For older sci films, we also have "The Invasion of the Saucer Men," but contrast that with "The Dalek Invasion of Earth."

Comment: "Absolutely no ambiguity" might be an overstatement. Perhaps some microbes were invading the body snatchers.

Comment: But still they come...